# Linking List Items together to enable mutual access

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, lookup-column

Consider having a single list holding a number of entities. I want them to be linked to form a kind of hierarchy or other type of network. It is easy to create a link pointing from one item to one or numerous other items, just by adding a lookup column and let users choose from the same list.

In the normal list display there will be links to click inside one item then, so that one can navigate along from one item to the next. However, there's no way back. I could add another lookup column to hold the elements pointing to the element currently displayed, but someone had to sync the links from both ends.

I could write a Flow to sync the elements, but this seems to be a real hassle, so I want to avoid that.

Is there something I'm missing? Can I connect two items with a single action so that both items "know" of each other and link to each other mutually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to create a linked list in SharePoint online? This is not quite doable for a out-of-box SharePoint list.

An option I can think of will be using Power Apps to customize the list form. Adding data connections to another list and filter all the items somehow connected with the current item.

Comment: You got it right. I intend to generate a linked list. In one direction it is safe to let the user create the link. The other way round (to make inverse traversal possible) it should be linked automagically.

Comment: @Ariser Then I do not think a SharePoint list can make a inverse link automatically without using a flow. All I can think of will be updating the item when a new item is created in another list and has a link to it.